# Order by clause in inner query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-administration

I have a scenario. I need to use `listagg` in 2 columns to put the data comma(,) separated. I have aliases in query so I can not use `group by` which is mandatory in  listagg. To resolve that I am taking the output in outer query and using listagg there and grouping the column.

Problem is my data is sorted by a column which is not in `select` clause. how can I maintain the order of data of inner query in outer query.
Or

Is there any possibility of taking column in outer query to use it for order by but not using in the `select` clause.

My query is like

```
    select A+10 AA,
    B*20 BB,
    CC ,
    DD
    from Tab1 order by M;
```

when I am using listagg then i modified the query

```
    select
    AA,
    BB
    listagg(CC,',') within group(order by CC),
    listagg(DD,',') within group(order by DD)
    from
    (
    select A+10 AA,
    B*20 BB,
    CC ,
    DD
    from Tab1 order by M
    )
     group by AA,BB
```

If you can see clearly our inner query is sored by column M which is not in select clause. How can i maintain `order by M` without taking in outer query or if i take column M in outer query how can i exclude the result.

Or is there any possibility of using `listagg` in inner query when I have aliases

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: It is simple Gordon...I have multiple coulmns in query....I am doing some operations in some columns...and I want to use listagg in columns....my question is how can we use group by when I have aliases in my select clause....because aliases doesn't work with group by.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases while grouping and you can use columns you don't display to sort.
The only restriction is that when not being grouped by, the columns to sort by need to be aggregated (`sum`, `max`, `min`, etc).

```
with testtab as (
  select 1 "AA", 10 "BB", 'aval1' "CC", 'bval1' "DD", 5 "SORTV" from dual
  union all select 2, 10, 'aval2', 'bval2', 4 "SORTV" from dual
  union all select 2, 30, 'aval3', 'bval3', 3 "SORTV" from dual
  union all select 4, 40, 'aval4', 'bval4', 2 "SORTV" from dual
  union all select 4, 40, 'aval5', 'bval5', 1 "SORTV" from dual)
select aa + 10 as "AA",
  bb * 20 as "BB",
  listagg(cc, ', ') within group (order by cc),
  listagg(dd, ', ') within group (order by dd)
from testtab
group by aa, bb
order by max(SORTV) asc
```

yields

```
AA     BB   LISTAGG(CC,',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYCC)     LISTAGG(DD,',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYDD)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14     800  aval4, aval5                              bval4, bval5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
12     600  aval3                                     bval3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
12     200  aval2                                     bval2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
11     200  aval1                                     bval1
```

Comment: Chriz...thanks for answer...but you know you are not using group by in aliases but in original column names.

Comment: @OnkarTiwari So you want to write i.e. `select 1 as "MyNumber" from dual group by "MyNumber"`? Can you please write some pseudocode to clarify what you want to do? Aliases of columns only affect the given name in the end result and may not be used otherwise in a query. Aliases of tables may be used trough the query to declare the used table (like `...from table t1 where t1.id = ...`). And if you have i.e. `case when col = 2 then col1 else col2 end` in your select, you need the exact same case expression in your group by.